# Filtering out multiple data.frame objects by given threshold simultaneously

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I have three data.frame objects that needs be to filter out by given threshold value simultaneously. I want to filter them out given threshold value for all data.frame objects. Can anyone give me some possible idea to accomplish this task?

## simulated data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  start=seq(1, by=9, len=18), end=seq(6, by=9, len=18),
  ID=letters[seq(1:18)], score=sample(1:25, 18, replace = FALSE))

df2 <- data.frame(
  start=seq(2, by=11, len=20), end=seq(8, by=11, len=20),
  ID=letters[seq(1:20)], score=sample(1:25, 20, replace = FALSE))

df3 <- data.frame(
  start=seq(4, by=11, len=25), end=seq(9, by=11, len=25),
  ID=letters[seq(1:25)], score=sample(1:25, 25, replace = FALSE))
```

## my attempt solution as follows:

filtering out given threshold:

```
df.li <- list(df1, df2, df3)
keep <- obj$score <= 12

test <- lapply(df.li, function(ele_) {
  keep <- ele_$score <= 12
  discard <- ele_[!keep]
  res <- data.frame(kee=keep,
                    dis=discard)
  return(res)
})
```

## my desired output:

if this approach can happen, I am going to group of filtering output for each data.frame object as list.

I think there might be better way to do this. Regarding the question I raised, what's would be better approach to accomplish this task? Can anyone point me out possible way to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
lst <- list(df1, df2, df3)

library(dplyr)
lapply(lst, function(x) { filter(x, score <= 12) })
```

Or as per mentionned by @akrun, in base `R`:

```
lapply(lst, function(x) { subset(x, score <= 12) })
```

Comment: Thanks all kind favor from you. Cheers

Comment: @Jurat Glad it helped :)

Comment: I want to summarize set of kept and non-kept instanced for each data.frame objects after filtering. Any way to achieve this output? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Jurat You could do maybe `lapply(lst, function(x) { split(x, x$score <= 12) })`